# Function which get number from array and set this number to other function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an issue with some piece of jquery code :)

The case is the following:

1. I have an array with numbers **var arr**.
2. I have a function **get_number()** which get each number from an
   array.
3. I have function with parameter **inner_li_height(number)**, which get max height of elements and set this height to other elements.

But something get crashed... :(

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/12n6vd58/)

HTML Structure

```
<div id="slide-1">
    <div class="inner-li">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="slide-2">
    <div class="inner-li">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="slide-3">
    <div class="inner-li">
        <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Array with numbers
    // Save the numbers in array

```
var arr = [];

$("div[id^='slide-']").each(function() {
    arr.push(parseInt( $(this).attr('id').split('-')\[1] ));
});
```

Get each number from array

```
// Get each number from array
function get_number() {
    $.each(arr, function(i, v) {
        return arr[i];
    });
}
```

Get maxHeight of inner-li element

```
// Get max-height of inner-li and set to the others with the same class
function inner_li_height(number) {

    var heights = $("div[id^='slide-" + number + "'] .inner-li").map(function () {
        return $(this).height();
    }).get(),

    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);

    console.log(maxHeight);

    $("div[id^='slide-" + number + "'] .inner-li").height(maxHeight);
}
```

And here call the function:

```
// Call function inner_li_height
inner_li_height(get_number);
```

I'll be happy if someone can help me :)

Comment: A couple of question: (1) What errors are you getting? (2) What does `get_numbers()` do? It looks like `get_numbers()` has no input, no output and no side-effects.

Comment: yes, get_numbers() has no ouput, but why? I want to use this function get_number() and set as a parammeter into inner_li_height()...

Comment: I deleted my answer so there is no further childish behaviour. Go fight stupidly for 10 points. This is supposed to be a helpful community, if an answer isn't quite correct for a distraction, there is enough to point it out for a quick fix, instead of rushing to post the correct one to scratch some points.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this single function that works on multiple DOM objects:

```
// Get max-height of inner-li and set to the others with the same class
function inner_li_height(attr) {

   $(attr).each(function(i,v) {
    var heights = $(attr).map(function () {
        return $(this).height();
    }).get();

    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);
    console.log(maxHeight);

    $(attr).height(maxHeight);
   });
}

inner_li_height('div[id^="slide-"] .inner-li');
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hr993Lsj/1/

Comment: Nice! :)... this working properly! But I preffered how to do this with two functions.

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: Considering that i was the first to answer corectly what's with the downvote?

Comment: This what I want to do with these two functions get_number() and inner_li_height() may be is more difficult and I just want to know how to do this.

Comment: I don't have permission to downvote... now I set your answer to correct.